# Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier (Node.js, Express, nact)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, actor

I'm building a simple app that demos the actor model using the [Nact](https://nact.io/) library.

The error I'm dealing with now is:

**Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "nact". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"**

Here is package.json:

```
 {
  "name": "actor-model-with-nact-demo-020120",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Adam's Actor Model with Nact Demo",
  "main": "server.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "nact": "^7.2.2",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon ./server.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Adam Dudley",
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

Here is server.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')

const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || '8000'

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
app.use('/static', express.static('./static/'))

app.get('/static', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/static/app.js'))
})

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/views/index.html')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening to requests on http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

Here is index.html:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
        <title>Adam's Actor Model with Nact Demo</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>Adam's Actor Model with Nact Demo</h1>
        <script src="static/app.js" type="module"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Here is app.js:

```
import { start, dispatch, stop, spawnStateless } from 'nact'

const system = start()

const greeter = spawnStateless(
  system,
  (msg, ctx) => console.log(`Hello ${msg.name}`),
  'greeter'
)

dispatch(greeter, { name: 'World!' })
```

Answer (score 1):

Author here. I'm not quite what the exact problem is here, but as it stands Nact is only officially supported on the server side. You  *may* be able to get it to work in the browser, but you may have to polyfill `setImmediate` to do so.

As Nact is a commonjs module, you'll need a bundler like Parcel or Webpack to be able to convert the library into the appropriate module format.